# can someone explain to me what technet subscription is all about?

Tags: technet

What is technet subscription all about?

Will it give me a license for an o/s, vs.net for use in production for "free"?

How does it differ from MSDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link (http://ladylicensing.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!87F95F1B5B21B01E!1241.entry) has more information (This is the blog of Licensing Escalation Manager at MS). To quote from the link:

"The software provided with an MSDN Subscription is for design, development, testing, and demonstration of applications in a non-production environment.

The software provided with TechNet Plus subscriptions is for evaluation purposes only."

Comment: ok so MSDN is for everything BUT deployment.

Comment: Yes, it looks you can use tools obtained through MSDN subscription to develop, test, demo etc, but not use them for production or deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Technet is basically demoware.  MSDN is real products.

Comment: could u use a sql server 2008 enterprise license in production? that wouldn't make sense though hehe.

Comment: It may not make sense, but you could.  The products in MSDN are the full products you can buy in the store... with several serial numbers for each.  Depending on which MSDN subscription you have, the products include OSs, Compilers, Databases, and all kinds of stuff that I never use. ;)

Comment: Er no you can't. Using in production is forbidden in the licence.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is designed for programmers.
Technet is designed for non-programming IT professionals.

Answer (score 0):

The way it was explained to me by a Microsoft guy.

Technet is intended for IT professionals to evaluate the various products and use it for providing support for said products. It's also used for planning deployments and testing your custom stuff like macros.

MSDN is intended for development professionals to build and support their own products on or around Microsoft products.

MSDN costs more but think about the target audience - professional developers.